# KeyError: Float64Index when running drop_duplicates

Tags: python, keyerror, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe with the duplicates in the t column, however when I run the drop_duplicates function the following error is returned. Could someone please explain how to fix this?

````
print(df.columns)

Index(['t', 'ax', 'ay', 'az', 'gx', 'gy', 'gz', 'mx', 'my', 'mz', 'movement',
       'hand', 'trial_1', 'trial_2', 'trial'],
      dtype='object')

df.drop_duplicates(subset= left_data.loc[:, 't'], keep='first', inplace=True, ignore_index=True) ```

KeyError: Int64IndeX
````

Comment: Please include the full error message to make this a [mcve].

Comment: Some sample data, or snippet where the error comes in the data would also be helpful